# joining same table without a common field

Tags: oracle

Oracle 11g/SQLPLUS

Given single table `TABLE` with three fields `ID, PARM, VALUE`, I want to select and group by based on different values of `VALUE`

E.g.

```
ID   PARM   VALUE

id1 accnt France-1    
id2 model Type-1    
id3 field blah    
id4 accnt France-2    
id5 model Type-1    
id6 field blah    
id7 accnt France-2    
id8 model Type-2    
id9 field blah    
id10 accnt Germany-1    
id11 model Type-1    
id12 field blah    
id13 accnt Germany-2    
id14 model Type-1    
id15 field blah
```

I want to count the number of models by `substr(accnt)`

```
German Type-1   2    
France Type-1   2    
France Type-2   1
```

I have something like this but I don't know how to JOIN T1 and T2 as there is no common field.

```
select substr(T1.value, 1, 6), T2.value, count(*)
from Table T1, Table T2
where T1.parm='accnt'
and T2.parm='model'
group by substr(T1.value, 1, 6), T2.value
```

Comment: It seems that two consecutive rows in your listing of rows of your table belong to one data item. So (id1, id2, id3) belong to the one item, (id4, id5, id6)  belong to another item and so on. The order of the rows in your listing is important. So it seems that your rows are ordered by the ID field, so id1<id2<id3<id4<... Is this the way you store your data?

Answer (score 0):

TABLE Table was actually linked via another TABLE Keys, so needed to add more clauses

```
select substr(T1.value, 1, 6), T2.value, count(*)
from Table T1, Table T2, Keys K1, Keys K2
where T1.parm='accnt'
and T2.parm='model'
and T1.id=K1.id
and T2.id=K2.id
and K1.id=K2.id -- this is the join 
group by substr(T1.value, 1, 6), T2.value;
```

Comment: I doubt that the actual query you used has: `and K1.id=K2.id` It's probably a join on some other column, not `id`

Comment: And the query will break when you have a country with a name of 4 or less characters (example values: `'USA-1'`, `'USA-2'`), or different countries that their first 6 characters are identical.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one:

```
SELECT substr (value, 1, 6) country
      ,value2
      ,count (*) cnt
  FROM (SELECT ID
              ,param
              ,value
              ,lead (value) OVER (ORDER BY 1) value2
          FROM tmp)
 WHERE param = 'accnt'
GROUP BY substr (value, 1, 6), value2;
```

**Output:**

```
COUNTRY VALUE2   CNT
------- ------ -----
France  Type-2     1
German  Type-1     2
France  Type-1     2

3 rows selected.
```